# How can I find the number of Jacobi Method iterations needed to reduce the error of a 100 factor?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the linear system 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 4 & 1 \\
    5 & 1 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -3 \\
    -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How do I find how many iterations we need to reduce the initial error $e^0=||x^0-x^*||$ of a 100 factor? Meaning the $k$ for which $e^k \le e^0/100$.

Comment: No, actually, which is weird. But let's assume (0,0,0) if needed.

Comment: Jacobi diverges for this system.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Unless you swap rows...

Comment: @PierreCarre Or columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the first and second rows, the iteration matrix for Jacobi's method is
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/5 & 2/5 \\1/4 & 0 &1/4 \\ -1/4 & 1/ 4 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

for which you have that $\|C\|_{\infty} = \frac 35$. Using the an a priori estimate for the fixed point error, you know that
$$
\|e^{(k)}\|_{\infty} \leq (3/5)^k \|x^{(0)}-x\|_{\infty}
$$

So you see that you can give an answer without being provided a particular $x^{(0)}$. If $(3/5)^k < 1/100 \Leftrightarrow k > 9$ the proposed condition is surely met.